# How does the backend safeguards data from a user extracting data of other user?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm implementing a backend with NestJS.
I have schemas of users, accounts and records.

I noticed that If a user has an account id of other user and tries to fetch the records of that account that does not belongs to him, he could.
I'm thinking of a strategy where only that specific user could fetch his data from the database.

Is there any lecture, book that you guys recommend me where I could read to know more about the implementation of backend agnostic to the framework and language?

Technically speaking, the record module is related to the account module using injection of dependencies where If the user deletes his account, the service will delete all related records to this account.

I was thinking on implementing a function to retrieve the account information where it has the user Id and if it does not matches to the userId of the account and the bearer token that has the user Id, it should throw an error.
However this approach is not desirable as I would have cycling dependency and I would double the request to the database to any CRUD operation related to records as I would consult the accountId information.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

The simplest way in NestJs in my opinion would be to **add a userId column in the db tables** that mark who the row in the table belongs to.

Then, **when you query the data, you query it together with the userId**. (`WHERE user_id = userId`)

If you have done your authentication properly, you should be getting the userId in the user object on every request.

Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Few things to consider before you start with user related back-end API

- Make use of authentication token to retrieve user-id and then user information from there.
- Never create a client facing endpoint which would retrieve any kind of user information with the help of user-id, for example: GET/POST/PUT /user/:id - this endpoint can be miss used by passing any random user-id. A better way to do this is to have user authentication token do the user information fetch. GET/POST/PUT /user - much better.
- In any case if you need to this, for example networking and social media app, that would have limited public access information with user's consent.
- Your need to do a good research on user permissions. https://www.okta.com/identity-101/what-is-token-based-authentication/

Comment: mmmm I see, I got some endpoints where these are only accessible using a bearer token and from there I get the user information. However I don't have like a role schemas for the users so any user If they have other accountId, could retrieve that data. I guess the best approach would be to attach a userId to each account and record so I can be sure that only that use is able to see his/her data.

Comment: And thanks for your input! Really appreciated Lior and Prajyot